# Clusterssh with publickey

Tags: command-line, ssh, openssh, cluster

how to login vps with sshpublickey with clusterssh ?

if i using 2 vps with password command

```
clusterssh username@ip username@ip
```

so how to using publickey ?

i use ubuntu 16.04

thank you

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

Comment: if using ssh -i key username@ip work, but i have 3 server same publickey from DO, so using clusterssh will make my work easier

Comment: I save it in the download folder, with the key and key.pub file because I downloaded the key in DO, so for the first time how do I set my default sshkey settings? where should I save the code?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1264462/edit) and add the new information you provided in the comments. Otherwise the question does not contain sufficient details and will be deleted by the moderators.

Comment: I have converted my comment to an answer. Please accept the answer below by clicking on the gray check mark ✔next to it and turn it green ✅. This will indicate that the answer is correct and help others with the same problem. You can also up-vote my answer to show your appreciation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem: Public Key is not in Default Location (from Comments)

The public keys were stored in the `Downloads` folder of each server. This is not the default location for storing authorized keys. As a result OP needed to specify the key location with the `-i` option for `ssh` like this:

```
ssh -i /path/to/key username@ip
```

This does not work with `clusterssh`.

## Solution:

### Step 1: Store the authorized keys in the default location

There is a command, part of `ssh`, to transfer the public key to the correct location of the remote server.

```
ssh-copy-id username@ip
```

You have to do this once for each server. To do this you will need to have:

#PasswordAuthentication yes

in the file: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for each server so that you can `ssh` into these servers using their passwords.

### Step 2: Remove the public keys from the "wrong" folder

Once the public keys are copied in the correct location please delete them from the `Downloads` folder in the server.

### Step 3: Confirm it works

Now you should be able to use `ssh` with key based authentication using the command:

```
shh username@ip
```

Once you confirm this works, confirm the corresponding `clustershh` command works:

```
clusterssh username@ip username@ip
```

When everything works, go to the next step.

### Step 4: Disable PasswordAuthentication

Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in each server and change the line:

```
#PasswordAuthentication yes
```

to read line this:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

## References:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Hope this helps